# How to exclude routes from renewing express cookie expiration date

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, express-session

Using `express js` with `express-session` I have this main classic session middleware which defines the cookie's `maxAge` to one hour.

```
var express         = require('express');
var session         = require('express-session');
var RedisStore      = require('connect-redis')(session);

var ExpressServer = express();

ExpressServer.use(
    session(
        {
            secret              : 'secret',
            //  Forces session to be saved even when unmodified
            resave              : false,
            rolling             : true,
            //  Forces session to be saved even when unmodified
            saveUninitialized   : true,
            //  Controls result of unsetting req.session (through delete, setting to null)
            unset               : 'destroy',
            cookie: {
                path: '/',
                proxy: secureCookie,
                secure: secureCookie,
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
            },
            store: new RedisStore(
                {
                    client: RedisClient
                }
            )
        }
    )
);
```

However, I have some routes which are called periodically (every 30 seconds) from the client to the server, let's say one of them is:

```
ExpressServer.get(
'/periodic',
function (req, res, next) {
    //doSomthing()
}
```

since this route is called periodically from the client, I need that it won't cause a renewal of the cookie's expiration date (in case the user leaves his browser open) and leave the current expiration date (from the last not-periodic route call)

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score -2):

Simply put the `ExpressServer.get('/periodic')` call before the `ExpressServer.use(session())` call. Or you can do something like:

```
var url = require('url');
var normalSessionOpts = {
    secret              : 'secret',
    //  Forces session to be saved even when unmodified
    resave              : false,
    rolling             : true,
    //  Forces session to be saved even when unmodified
    saveUninitialized   : true,
    //  Controls result of unsetting req.session (through delete, setting to null)
    unset               : 'destroy',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        proxy: secureCookie,
        secure: secureCookie,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
    },
    store: new RedisStore(
        {
            client: RedisClient
        }
    )
};
var nonRollingSessionOpts = Object.assign({}, normalSessionOpts, { rolling: false });
var normalSession = session(normalSessionOpts);
var nonRollingSession = session(nonRollingSessionOpts);

ExpressServer.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url)
    return parsedUrl.pathname === '/periodic'
        ? nonRollingSession(req, res, next)
        : normalSession(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Regarding your first option, I tried it but it doesn't seem to help since the `maxAge` parameter stays the same from the call before, so it's renewing it anyway. Could you please explain your second option? how will turning the `rolling` option off will help here? the `maxAge` will still affect the session.

Comment: @TomG [according to the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#rolling) setting `rolling` to `true` means that "The expiration is reset to the original [`maxAge`](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#cookiemaxage), resetting the expiration countdown." So setting it to `false` for that specific route means that the session cookie will not be updated with a new expiration time.

Comment: well, I tried it and it didn't work. I do "touch" the session, so maybe this is the problem? I need to use the session data, just not to update the expiration date